# Effective way to implement accumulate sum with ARM NEON

Tags: optimization, arm, neon

I Want to implement accumulate sum with neon. Following is my pseudo code.
    uint32_t pDst[16];
    unsigned char buf[16] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
    uint8x16_t eles = vld1q_u8(buf);
    uint8x8_t lowEles8 = vget_low_u8(eles);
    uint8x8_t highEles8 = vget_high_u8(eles);

```
//do add with 3 pass for lowEles
uint16x8_t lowEles16 = vaddl_u8(lowEles8, vext_u8(zeroVec8, lowEles8, 7));
lowEles16 = vaddq_u16(lowEles16, vextq_u16(zeroVec, lowEles16, 6));
lowEles16 = vaddq_u16(lowEles16, vextq_u16(zeroVec, lowEles16, 4));

//do add with 3 pass for highEles
uint16x8_t highEles16 = vaddl_u8(highEles8, vext_u8(zeroVec8, highEles8, 7));
highEles16 = vaddq_u16(highEles16, vextq_u16(zeroVec, highEles16, 6));
highEles16 = vaddq_u16(highEles16, vextq_u16(zeroVec, highEles16, 4));

// save for the first 8 elements
uint32x4_t res32x4 = vmovl_u16(vget_low_u16(lowEles16));
vst1q_u32(pDst, res32x4);
res32x4 = vmovl_u16(vget_high_u16(lowEles16));
vst1q_u32(pDst+4, res32x4);

// save for the last 8 elements
int preSum = vgetq_lane_u32(res32x4, 3);
uint32x4_t preSum32x4 = vdupq_n_u32(preSum);
res32x4 = vaddq_u32(vmovl_u16(vget_low_u16(lowEles16)), preSum32x4);
vst1q_u32(pDst+8, res32x4);
res32x4 = vaddq_u32(vmovl_u16(vget_high_u16(lowEles16)), preSum32x4);
vst1q_u32(pDst+12, res32x4);
```

**I found my implementation is slow than native c++ implementation**. Are there any suggestions

Comment: Ultimately, this isn't a SIMD operation, so it's understandable that NEON sucks at it. The SIMD approach which _would_ be a good fit for NEON would be to rearrange the data such that you can use a direct vectorisation of the basic C++ algorithm to compute multiple cumulative sums in parallel. If you find yourself operating _across_ the lanes of a vector for reasons other than combining partial results at the end of a loop, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @Notlikethat: What? Computing a the sum of an array is *absolutely* a thing SIMD excels at. The main problem is that the array is *tiny* and NEON is usually not integrated as closely into  the CPU core as SSE is, so for small arrays the latency from moving the result back to the integer registers is pretty bad. Otherwise, a *decent* implementation of a vectorized array sum is *extremely* fast. So fast, in fact, that you can expect your compiler to vectorize well written C/C++ code automatically.

Comment: @EOF I agree that simply accumulating an array, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] => 36` is fair NEON fodder, and had half-written a "just use `vpaddl`/`vpadd`, or simply `addv` for AArch64" answer before I realised that this isn't that - it's generating a _cumulative sum_, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] => [1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36]`. There are zero integer core operations here, just pure NEON, but when each element of the output depends on a combination of different numbers of elements of the input, there's just no simple parallelism to be had without turning it sideways (i.e. multiple input streams).

Comment: @Notlikethat So are they any tricks on neon to implement the cumulative sum efficiently